# How can I debug variable of [Function] type?

Tags: javascript

Some functions are set into variables.
And I want to debug what kind of function is set there?
However that function can non be changed.
In this situation, how should I debug?

```
var something = returnfunc(); //returnfunc() return function type object
console.log(something);

[Function]
```

Comment: What's the actual issue? There isn't different types of functions, all functions are just functions.

Comment: Maybe instead of returnfunc() you should be writing returnfunc without brackets.
And returnfunc should be the function you are expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `toString` in the function to get a string representation of the source code ;)

E.g.:

```
let fn = (a, b) => a + b; 
console.log(fn.toString())
// (a, b) => a + b
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant check type of object that has value of function:

```
var something = returnfunc;
console.log(typeof something);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking how to identify the function returned by `returnfunc`. If you use an anonymous function, it is harder to debug because that function is not identified with a name:

```
function returnfunc () {
  return function () {
    return 'I am an anonymous function'
  }
}

var fn = returnfunc() // [Function]
```

But you can just give the function a name:

```
function returnfunc () {
  return function foo () {
    return 'I am a named function'
  }
}

var fn = returnfunc() // [Function: foo]
```